# NLog to Azure Blob, how to reduce access with Shared Access Signature or Connection String

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage, nlog

I have a console app, that logs to azure blob storage successfully with this extension
https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.AzureBlobStorage/README.md

It uses the connection string of the azure blob storage that gives full access to the storage.

Is it possible to limit the access to only one container within this storage may be with shared access signature instead of the full connection string?

Comment: You can create a service SAS token, that has specific write access to the container, and then use this SAS token in your console app. See [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create#create-a-service-sas-for-a-blob-container) to create service SAS token

Comment: yes how to use it with nlog?

Comment: Can you try something like: `BlobEndpoint=https://account.blob.core.windows.net;SharedAccessSignature=sasToken` for the connection string?

Comment: @fred_ You can use `serviceUri` instead. Ex `serviceUri="https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net"` and it will use the managed-idenity with help from `AzureServiceTokenProvider` (As described in the `README.md`)

Comment: @RolfKristensen - Managed identity solution might not work in this scenario as the application mentioned by OP is a console application. Managed identity would work if the application is running in Azure.

Comment: @GauravMantri Maybe it will work if having setup an existing logon-session before initializing, then `AzureServiceTokenProvider` will use the existing session.

Comment: Seems it should be possible to built a [Shared Access Signature URI](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-2.md#add-a-method-to-try-container-operations-using-a-shared-access-signature) and then just assign that URI to the `serviceUri`-property. Can assign using the NLog Layout with [NLog Config Variable](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Var-Layout-Renderer) or [NLog GlobalDiagnosticsContext](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/GDC-Layout-Renderer).